# Is this proof correct (measure theory)?

Tags: mathematical-economics, proof, real-analysis, proof-reference

I'm trying to prove the following statement:
[image]

I did the following proof but i donno if it makes sense:

**Proof of** $(\Rightarrow)$ **direction:**

Assume $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Assume also $\{A_n\} \subset \mathcal{F}$ and $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ for all $i \neq j$. Hence, from the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra, $\cup_{n=1}^\infty \in \mathcal{F}$.

**Proof of** $(\Leftarrow)$ **direction:**

Assume $\{A_n\} \subset \mathcal{F}$ and $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ for all $i \neq j \Rightarrow \cup_{n=1}^\infty \in \mathcal{F}$. We need to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma algebra. Assume by contradiction that $\mathcal{F}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is an algebra, assuming that $\mathcal{F}$ is not a sigma algebra means assuming that $\{A_n\} \subset \mathcal{F}$ and $\cup_{n=1}^\infty \notin \mathcal{F}$. By definition of $\{A_n\} \subset \mathcal{F}$, we have that $\forall A_i \in \{A_n\} \Rightarrow A_i \in \mathcal{F}$. Moreover, since $\mathcal{F}$ is an algebra, $A_i^c \in \mathcal{F}$, $\cup_{n=1}^n A_i \in \mathcal{F}$, and $\cup_{n=1}^n A_i^c \in \mathcal{F}$. Now define $\tilde{A_1} = A_1$, $\tilde{A_2} = A_2 \cap (\cup_{i \neq 2} A_i^c)$ and so on. But then $\tilde{A_i} \cap \tilde{A_j} = \emptyset$ for all $i \neq j$. Hence, by hypothesis, $\cup_{n=1}^\infty \in \mathcal{F}$ so we reach a contradiction.

Could you please review the proof and provide me feedback?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In addition to the suggestions of Michael Greineker (avoid the  proof by contradiction) you should explicitely point out that  $\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_i= \cup_{n=1}^\infty \tilde A_i$.

Because the point is that an arbitrary union of a countable collection of sets in an algebra is also the union of a collection of (two by two) disjoint sets of the algebra: I think this is the idea underlying  your proof.

Answer (score 3):

The first direction is fine, the second has some small problems and some scope for improvement.

There is the notational issue that $\cup_{n=1}^\infty \in \mathcal{F}$ should be $\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \in \mathcal{F}$.

$\tilde{A_2} = A_2 \cap (\cup_{i \neq 2} A_i^c)$ means that $\tilde{A_2}$ is the set of all points that are in $A_2$ and are not in some $A_i$ with $i\neq 2$. This does in general not work, let $A_1=\{0\}$, and $A_i=\{1\}$ for $i\neq 1$. Then $\tilde{A_i}=\emptyset$ for $i\neq 1$. What works is $\tilde{A_i} = A_i \cap (\cup_{j<i} A_j^c)$. With this change, the proof works.

However, the contradiction argument is superfluous. You are then directly showing that a field that is closed under disjoint countable unions is closed under arbitrary countable unions.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense. Thanks a lot for your feedback!!